# get Authorization Header from Recess Request

Tags: php, http-headers, authorization, recess

I'm using the recess framework. Does somebody knows how to get the Authorization header from the request.

Normally, to get the request, we do `$this->request`, but how to extract the Authorization header which is in a form

```
Authorization:Basic  jadfasdbaHGDWDSJDN==
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the request arrives at the server, the username and password is already decoded, to get the

```
$Username=$this->request->username;
$Password=$this->request->password;
```